# Как правильно использовать функцию RegEnumKeyExA

Tags: c++, winapi

Я использую следующий код

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HKEY key;
    long op = RegOpenKeyA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software", &key);
    if(op == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        char* name = new char[MAX_PATH];
        memset(name, 0, MAX_PATH);
        DWORD nameSize = 0;
        for(int i = 0;;i++)
        {
            op = RegEnumKeyExA(key, i, name, &nameSize, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            printf("%s\n", name);
            if(op == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
            {
                break;
            }
            if(op != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                printf("stop");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В самом первом проходе у меня завершается цикл с выводом в консоль `stop` в переменную `name` после `RegEnumKeyExA` ничего не попадает, ровно как и `nameSize` равен нулю вопрос что я не так делаю для вывода подразделов реестра?

Comment: Размер буфера при вызове RegEnumKeyExA указан равным 0. Кроме того, следует использовать W функции.

Comment: @user7860670 Спасибо изменив размер буфера на `MAX_PATH` и установление `MAX_PATH` после каждого вызова `RegEnumKeyExA` решило мою проблему. Не могли-бы вы дать ответ что-бы я засчитал его правильным. А так-же есть вопрос почему следует использовать W функции?

Comment: A функции - это наследие старых версий Windows, не имевших поддержки юникода. Многие из них внутренне делают преобразование текста и вызов соответствующей W функции. Так что помимо отсутствия поддержки юникода, при использовании A функций вы можете еще получать оверхед на ровном месте.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Перед самим вызовом `RegEnumKeyExA` укажите размер буфера, куда ложатся данные, например:

```
DWORD nameSize = MAX_PATH
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-answer).